# Angles in 3 Dimensions

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, 3d, angle

Consider the following points;

A(0,-4,4)

B(0,4,4)

C(0,-4,0)

D(0,4,0)

E(x,y,0)

If all of these are connected, it leaves a rectangular-based pyramid with a variable vertex (E). Is there any way to compare the angle at this vertex as x and y or are angles limited to a single plane involved in the shape? TO put this into a bit more context, the closer E is to the origin, logically, this 'angle' or measurement would be larger than if E was farther away.

Best Regards,

Yazan

Comment: Excuse me but what angle of vertex (E) do you want to compare? 
We are in a 3D, do you want yo compare a 2D angle?

Comment: There's a formula here:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle. Look for Pyramid and browse till the end of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In the point $E$ are concurrent four sides of the pyramid $\overline{EA}$, $\overline{EB}$, $\overline{EC}$, $\overline{ED}$.

If you want find the angles between any two of them you have to find the vectors parallel to the sides, e.g.
$$
\vec {EA}=(-x,-4-y,4)^T \qquad \vec {EB}=(-x,4-y,4)^T
$$
than the angle $\theta$ between them is given can be found by means of the dot product:

$$
\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{EA}\cdot \vec{EB}}{|\vec {EA}||\vec{EB}|} \right)
$$

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. However, the application I am trying to work towards is a comparison of the angle available. There is a way around this but I am unsure if it is mathematically sound. Can I simply add all four of these angles and use that value for different points of E for comparison?

Comment: You can add the four angles and note that the sum has its maximum value $2\pi$ when $E$ is the plane of the basis.

Comment: Sorry, one last question: What is it you mean by "plane of the basis"? And why do they add up to 2pi?

Comment: I've added a figure to my answer. The plane of the basis is the plane that contain $A,B,C,D$ , that is the plane $x=0$. You can see that if $E$ is a point on this plane (i.e. the height of the pyramid is null) than it is a poin on the side $CD$ and the sum of the angle with the common vertex at $E$  is $360°$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is  a solid angle.

If a spherical patch on a unit sphere has area $A$ then its solid angle is $A$ steradians.

A spherical cap  boundary of latitude $\phi$ has area $ 2 \pi R^2 (1-\sin \phi) $ so its subtended solid angle $ 2 \pi  (1-\sin \phi)$ steradians. In general also defined as integral curvature $\int KdA$ which occurs as one of the four terms in Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Recently I asked for $\Omega$ [of Circle rim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135522/solid-angle-subtended-by-polar-cap) at off-center location.

In other cases it is not well defined, afik. I for one tend to define it (so with caution!) as follows:

Connect every point of a closed non-intersecting 3d curve poly-line in space to E (the view-point) forming an oblique developable "cone" with green p-line base boundary. Call it P*L3cone*. Let the cone intersect the unit sphere along a black contour PL3 in rough sketch.

[image]

The solid angle of PL3 imo is the area enclosed by such projection/ intersection on unit sphere by the PL3cone  ( extended if necessary.. i.e., when slant generators are short of unity length).

In your case the PL3 is a quadrangle with a boundary of four great circles whose internal angle sum exceeds $ 2 \pi$. In eccentric configurations the intersections would be small circles.