# Solid angle subtended by polar cap

Tags: 3d, spherical-trigonometry, solid-angle

Solid angle subtended by polar cap at  unit sphere center  latitude $\phi$  is

$$ 2 \pi (1- \sin \phi_c)$$

[image]

What is the solid angle it subtends at other unsymmetric  points inside the sphere like above ... as a function of radius , latitude and longitude: $(r<1,\phi, \theta)$?

Comment: Your formula is wrong, it does not even match dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. was typo, ( forgot removing $R^2$) now dimensionless.

Comment: You also did not mention what $\theta$ is

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as it stands.  There's no area at a point.  Can you describe the area you mean?

Comment: The polar cap has an area. An arbitrary point inside sphere is taken. Makes sense?

Comment: @Narasimham Your note still made no sense, but your diagram makes a little.  You are talking about moving the apex of the cone from the center of the sphere to another point; the 2d version would be finding the arc intercepted by an angle with vertex at a random point inside the circle.

Comment: It would have to be a function of the location of the apex of the cone, and it would be far from trivial, a pretty messy double integral.

Answer (score 1):

From inside the sphere, outside the spherical cap, the spherical cap subtends the same solid angle as the circular disc at the base of the spherical cap.  (You can prove this by examining the rays from the chosen point. If they intersect with the spherical cap, they intersect the circular disk, and vice versa.)

Unfortunately, the solid angle subtended by an arbitrary circular disc involves elliptic integrals (which is kind of obvious, if you think about it).  There are a number of nuclear physics papers dealing with calculating this efficiently, as many sensors are circular, and knowing the solid angle the sensor subtends from the sample, is needed to derive the sample properties from the sensor data.  For proper mathematical examination, see e.g. Paxton, F. [Solid Angle Calculation for a Circular Disk](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1716590), *Review of Scientific Instruments* 30 (1959), pp. 254-258 ([PDF at UMich](http://www.umich.edu/%7Eners312/CourseLibrary/SolidAngleOfADiskOffAxis.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Can we  find $\Lambda$ as a function of rotations about two orthogonal axes from the reference?

Answer (score 0):

The formulae for the generic case are in https://vixra.org/abs/1403.0977 . From this it seems no elliptic integrals are needed.